# Nested loops with different and dependant steps

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, while-loop

I need to make an algorithm to perform a task with 2 while loops.
I will explain what it is I want to achieve. I need to make a loop based on length of h value. Well the loop should take big steps with f.ex. 3 or 2 or 4, the item from while or for loop should check a condition or equation. I need to check when or which value of item gives zero value to n in equation.
When n value reaches zero, I need to perform a smaller step with 0.1. Because I need to be more precis.  There is no need to start the loop with small step in the beginning it slows performance time, and it is just interesting to know exact small value of item which gives zero to n equation. And this is true when n equation closes to zero value.

**To illustrate the example:**
Loop 1 starts and take big steps.

```
h = 50
st = 10
loop 1 starts
0 ,       3,        6,      9,       12,     15,     18,  21,  24 …………………                            #<--------   steps from h value 
25.0 , 22.0 , 19.0,  16.0, 13.0, 10.0, 7.0, 4.0, 1.0 …………………                                         #<--------  calculate values from n equation
                                                  If n <= 2 or n>= -2:
                                                  |_____ loop 2 starts with: 
                                                          24.0, 23.9 , 23.8, 23.7, 23.6, ……………..     #<--------   small steps iterate with hj = 24+st
                                                          0.4,  0.3 , 0.1, 0.0, -1.0, ……………..        #<--------  calculate values from n equation
                                                          Calculate n values from n equation
                                                          M = 2 + n
                                                          If (n <= 0 or n>= -1) and M==2 :           #<--------   If statement is fullfilled then return some values and quit loop 2 and loop 1.
                                                             Return n, itemstep from loop 2, M
                                                           
                                                          Elif (n <= 0 or n>= -1) and M!=2:
                                                             Quit loop 2 and 1                       #<--------   If statement is not fullfilled then quit loop 2 and loop 1.
```

The reason for **n >= -1**, because we could start step from 50 down to 0 and n value can be negative as well.
I have tried to figure it out with code below, but it seems not working, is it a way to generate such code in while or for loop.

```
M = 2         #<---------- to check conditions
j = 0 
st = 10 
h = 50        #<---------- to iterate over length h
n = h/2 - j   #<---------- to calculate n values (n equation)
result =[]    
while j <=h:    #<----------  loop 1
    n = h/2 - j
    if n <= 3 or n >= -3:  #<---------- if this is satisified then start loop2 
        print(n)
        i=j
        while i < 10+st:       #<----------  loop 2
            n = h/2-i         
            M = 2+n
            if (n <= 0 or n>= -1) and M==2:
                result.append(n, i, M)       #<----------  return values
                i = 70+j                     #<---------- stop loop 2 and loop 1
                j = h+70
            elif  (n <= 0 or n>= -1) and M!=2:  #<---------- if this is not satisified then quit loop2 and loop 1
                i = 70+j                     #<---------- stop loop 2 and loop 1
                j = h+70
            i +=0.1
            j += i
    j += 3
```

Comment: is the objective to make n 0? intuively many of your 'or' logic should be 'and'

Comment: Yes, this is the point to get 0.

Comment: if you only need the big step mode once, then move to small steps, you do not have to nest the loops. Should be one while followed by another while. Do you mind fix the psdudo code to use 'and' that will help others to understand what you are doing

Comment: If you're looking to minimize the value of the function `lambda h, j: h / 2 - j`, maybe https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html could help...

Comment: @AKX, this is indeed interesting to find minimize, my task is goal seeking as in excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you some. (Not exactly what you wanted but it is a start)

```
j = 0
h = 50
while j <= h:
    n = h/2 - j
    if -3 <= n <= 3:
        i = j
        while i < j + 10:
            n = h/2 - i
            if n <= 0:
                j = h + 70
                print(n)
                break
            i += 0.1
    j += 3
```

or you could do it like this.

```
j = 0
h = 50
while j <= h:
  n = h/2 - j
  if -3 <= n <= 3:
    break
  j += 3

i = j
while i < j + 10:
  n = h/2 - i
  if n <= 0:
      print(n)
      break
  i += 0.1
```